# How to post 1million records(Excel) from mvc controller to web-api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

Our application uses AngularJS -> MVC-> WebAPI-> EF architecture.
when uploading from Angularjs, It used to work for 50K records by setting up the following in web.config

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="100000" />


<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="300000000" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

**MVCController.cs**

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;

            var CBListData = serializer.Serialize(CBList);



            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(
                                          "api/PostCLIENTValues", JArray.Parse(CBListData));
```

However i need to upload an excel file which contains 1 or 1.5million records which the above code fails to serialize and pass as json. it is throwing  below error

```
"cannot evaluate the expression"
```

what will be a viable approach here?
Can i send directly from angularJS to webAPI or is there any workaround to send from MVC->WebAPI

Comment: "the above code fails to serialize"? How does it fail? Errors?

Comment: why you need 1kk records on client? use pagination or some sort of filter to reduce amount of records

Comment: @spender yes it fails for 1.5 million records.

Comment: @teovankot am sending 1.5 million records to webapi  to insert in to db. like am doing bulk insert here

Comment: You file is larger, you likely just need to increase your maximum length values.

Why don't you look at the size of the excel file, and use that as a guide for those properties?

Comment: What about to send excel file itself and then read it and use bulk insert?

Comment: @SivaRajini We know it fails. How does it fail? When your car doesn't work, do you take it to the garage and say "it's broken" and hope they figure it out, or do you describe to them how it's broken?

Comment: how about reading the file asynchronously. Read this also http://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/dealing-with-large-files-in-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: @teovankot we are doing some validation in mvc controller after that only we are sending it to webapi. we have to send either bulk json from mvc to webapi or angular to webapi.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps:

1. Take a temporary file-token from server.
2. Upload file in chunks (post chunk with the file-token to identify it), save the file chunk in server's temporary folder, returning the status of the uploaded chunk. (if fails, re-upload)
3. Once last chunk is uploaded, combine the binary file chunks to single file and import it to DB.

Comment: could you please be more specific details.we are not saving while anywhere. we are just reading the file and sending the data to webapi for inserting in to db. we are using sqlbulkcopy to insert bulk records into db

Comment: You can either save it at some folder or save it in memory (byte[]). But keeping data in memory is not/never recommended.